# How to solve the unexpected pyinstaller exception "pyqt5_plugins distribution was not found"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe

I wrote a window application using the PyQt5 library. After compiling by "pyinstaller" when trying to run the exe file, the following error occurs:

[image: Error]

I tried to reinstall pyqt5_plugins library, compile the program without the "--windowed" option, or remove errors from the "warn-main.txt" file, nothing helped. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```sh
--copy-metadata pyqt5_plugins --copy-metadata qt5_tools --copy-metadata qt5_applications --hidden-import qt5_tools --collect-submodules qt5_applications --collect-submodules pyqt5_plugins
```

**EDIT**: 
For me I need several `copy-metadata` and `collect-submodules` to work.

Comment: Yes, thats helped but now I have "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtDesigner'" error and --copy-metadata with collect-submodules doesnt work

Comment: emm... that's hard. i have a conversation with rokm and he states that those packages (that you're using) are "trying or planning to override the Qt libraries ..." which doesn't coordinate with pyinstaller's Qt hook well. see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/pull/286#issuecomment-894214870 .I'm sad that I couldn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try go to the line where latest traceback shows and check if the import statement is ok.
In my case I did

```
from pyqt5_plugins.examplebuttonplugin import QtGui
```

and when I correct it to

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
```

It works.